# NoClassDefFoundError in ParseUtils

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse for push notification i am getting following error

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: notifications.ParseUtils$1
        at notifications.ParseUtils.registerParse(ParseUtils.java:33)
        at com.techieweb.solutions.pickeronline.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:20)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4590)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using this for reference
     http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

This is my ParseUtils.java class

```
  public class ParseUtils {

private static String TAG = ParseUtils.class.getSimpleName();

public static void verifyParseConfiguration(Context context) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID) || TextUtils.isEmpty(AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please configure your Parse Application ID and Client Key in AppConfig.java", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity) context).finish();
    }
}

public static void registerParse(Context context) {
    // initializing parse library
    Parse.initialize(context, AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
 //Shows error heree
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(AppConfig.PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
        }
    });
}

public static void subscribeWithEmail(String email) {
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

    installation.put("email", email);

    installation.saveInBackground();

    Log.e(TAG, "Subscribed with email: " + email);
}
}
```

and this is MyApplication

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;

    // register with parse
    ParseUtils.registerParse(this);
}


public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}
}
```

This is NotificationUtils class

```
public class NotificationUtils {

private String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils() {
}

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, Intent intent) {

    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;

    if (isAppIsInBackground(mContext)) {
        // notification icon
        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

        int smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_push;

        int mNotificationId = AppConfig.NOTIFICATION_ID;

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(smallIcon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notification);
    } else {
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 *
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: where is your NotificationUtils class??

Comment: @VivekMishra I have added NotificationUtils class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the error by removing

```
  ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(AppConfig.PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
    }
});
```

and using only

```
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/pushservicesetdefaultpushcallback-has-now-been-depreciated-what-can-be-used

Answer (score 1):

> NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when the definition of class in not
>   available during runtime. This error also indicates that the
>   definition of the class was found during the compilation of the
>   application, but it is not available in the application’s classpath
>   during runtime.

### Your Logcat throws

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: notifications.ParseUtils$1
        at notifications.ParseUtils.registerParse(ParseUtils.java:33)
```

Make sure, your `NotificationUtils` calling or not .

Comment: how to check whether NotificationUtils calling or not .

Comment: @Priyanka You can  do `clean-Rebuild-restart-Sync` at first .

Comment: Notification is not called. Error is shown on ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(AppConfig.PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback()

Comment: @Priyanka using `jar` or calling from `build.gradle` section

Comment: calling from build.gradle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99688/discussion-between-priyanka-and-intellij-amiya).